# Serializing derived classes from an abstract class using boost::serialization

Tags: c++, abstract-class, virtual-functions, boost-serialization

I am trying to serialize derived classes from an abstract class and I am getting some (obvious) errors.

Here is the code (ran using g++ -std=c++17 XXXX.cpp -Wall -larmadillo -lboost_serialization):

```
#include <boost/archive/binary_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/binary_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/assume_abstract.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/serialization.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/split_member.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/export.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/unique_ptr.hpp>

#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>


class Car {
public:
    //Car() = default;
    //virtual double getInfo() = 0;
    virtual char const* type() const = 0;
    virtual ~Car() = default;

private:
    friend class boost::serialization::access;
    template <class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive& ar, const unsigned int version) {};
};

class Audi : public Car {
public:
    char const* type() const override { return "Audi"; }
    //double getInfo() override { return 2.2; }
    Audi(std::string owner1, int hp1, std::string second_owner1, std::string country1)
        {
        owner = owner1;
        hp = hp1;
        second_owner = second_owner1; 
        country = country1;
        }
    Audi() = default;

    std::string owner;
    int hp{};
    std::string second_owner;
    std::string country;    
private:
    friend class boost::serialization::access;
    template <class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive& ar, const unsigned int version) {
        ar & boost::serialization::base_object<Car>(*this); //https://theboostcpplibraries.com/boost.serialization-class-hierarchies
        ar & owner;
        ar & hp;
        ar & second_owner;
        ar & country;
    }

};

BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT(Audi);
BOOST_SERIALIZATION_ASSUME_ABSTRACT(Car); //Tell Boost that Car is abstract



int main() {
    std::string str;
   {
        std::unique_ptr<Car> audi = std::make_unique<Audi>("Wilma", 3, "Rene", "Argentina");
        audi->type();


        std::stringstream strs;
        boost::archive::binary_oarchive ar(strs);
        ar& audi;

        str = strs.str();
    }

    {
        std::unique_ptr<Car> audi; //= std::make_unique<Audi>();

        std::stringstream strs(str);
        boost::archive::binary_iarchive ar(strs);
        ar& audi;
        //dynamic_cast<Audi>(audi); Tried using casting but am unfamiliar with it -- perhaps this is the issue?

        std::cout << "audi: hp=" << audi->hp << " owner=" << audi->owner <<"\n";

    }

}
```

and I am getting the errors:

```
audi_seri.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
audi_seri.cpp:84:36: error: cannot dynamic_cast ‘audi’ (of type ‘class std::unique_ptr<Car>’) to type ‘class Audi’ (target is not pointer or reference)
             dynamic_cast<Audi>(audi);
                                    ^
audi_seri.cpp:86:47: error: ‘class Car’ has no member named ‘hp’
             std::cout << "audi: hp=" << audi->hp << " owner=" << audi->owner <<"\n";
                                               ^~
audi_seri.cpp:86:72: error: ‘class Car’ has no member named ‘owner’
             std::cout << "audi: hp=" << audi->hp << " owner=" << audi->owner <<"\n";
```

Now, I know why this is happening -- Car doesn't have these variables. But how can I solve this to where the solution can work for many derived classes that could have different members? Perhaps to solve this I have to use casting?

To give more insight as to why I am trying to do this. I initially wanted to have void serialize() in Car as a virtual function but that doesn't work with templates. And hence I came to the above code with the help of https://theboostcpplibraries.com/boost.serialization-class-hierarchies

Here is the old code with with void serialize as a virtual function:

```
class Car {
public:
      virtual double getInfo() = 0;

private:
   template <typename Archive> //This is the problem I am trying to solve: templates cannot be virtual
   virtual void serialize(Archive& ar, unsigned int version) = 0;
};

class Audi : public Car {
    public:
        char const* type() const override { return "Audi"; }
        //double getInfo() override { return 2.2; }
        Audi(std::string owner1, int hp1, std::string second_owner1, std::string country1)
            {
            owner = owner1;
            hp = hp1;
            second_owner = second_owner1; 
            country = country1;
            }
        Audi() = default;

        std::string owner;
        int hp{};
        std::string second_owner;
        std::string country;    
    private:
        template <class Archive>
        void serialize(Archive& ar, const unsigned int version) {
            ar & owner;
            ar & hp;
            ar & second_owner;
            ar & country;
        }

    };

    BOOST_SERIALIZATION_ASSUME_ABSTRACT(Car); //Tell Boost that Car is abstract



    int main() {
        std::string str;
       {
            std::unique_ptr<Car> audi = std::make_unique<Audi>("Wilma", 3, "Rene", "Argentina");


            std::stringstream strs;
            boost::archive::binary_oarchive ar(strs);
            ar& audi;

            str = strs.str();
        }

        {
            std::unique_ptr<Car> audi; //= std::make_unique<Audi>();

            std::stringstream strs(str);
            boost::archive::binary_iarchive ar(strs);
            ar& audi;
            //dynamic_cast<Audi>(audi);

            std::cout << "audi: hp=" << audi->hp << audi->hp<< " owner=" << "\n";

        }

    }
```

Comment: Which lines cause the code to work when commented out? Please indicate in your code which lines those are. We can't see line numbers.

Comment: I updated the question and minimized the code. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: You may just need `dynamic_cast<Audi &>(*audi)`?

Comment: Thanks for the message. I just tried it right before the code `std::cout << "audi: hp=" << audi->hp << " owner=" << audi->owner <<"\n";` and I get the same errors regarding `audi->hp` and `audi->owner`.

Comment: @mikamul yes, `dynamic_cast` returns a new pointer or reference with the correct type, you need to store that and use it for further access. It does not change the type of the already existing variable (nothing can).

Comment: @Quentin I changed the code to `Audi& d =dynamic_cast<Audi &>(*audi);    
        std::cout << "audi: hp=" << d.hp << " owner=" << d.owner <<"\n";` and it compiles but running ./a.out I get `terminate called after throwing an instance of 'boost::archive::archive_exception'
  what():  unregistered void cast 4Audi<-3Car
[1]    26246 abort      ./a.out`

Comment: I found the mistake. It was in my code that was a little different than the code I posted (the code I posted was correct). It works now, thanks a lot. Out of curiosity I tried `Audi d =dyn...` compared to `Audi& d =...` and both worked. Do you perhaps know why that is?

Comment: @mikamul this just creates a new `Audi` which is a copy of the one held by `audi`.

Comment: @Quentin true, but then it shouldn't work without using Audi& right? I'm confused why both work.

Comment: Why souldn't it? `dynamic_cast<Audi &>(*audi)` returns a reference to the `Audi` pointed to by `audi`, and you can either continue referring to that same object by using a reference yourself, or make a copy of it.

Comment: Ah right. Got it thanks. Can you make a post so I can click your answer as correct?

Comment: @Quentin Another question, why after the deserialization do we need to cast, so that we can access specific members?

Comment: @mikamul same as always: the compiler only has the static types that you provide, through declarations or casts. It cannot deduce that at runtime `*audi`'s dynamic type will be `Audi`, only that its static type is `Car`. I don't think this would make a useful Q&A as it is all unrelated to boost.serialization, it's only regular type erasure.